# .Net Core WebApi refuses connection in Docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying out Docker with a small WebApi which I have written in dotnet core.

The Api seems to work fine because when I run it with `dotnet run` it starts normally and is reachable on port 5000. But when I run it in a Docker container it starts, but I cannot reach it on the exposed/mapped port. I'm running Docker on Windows 10 withing VirtualBox.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:latest
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet restore
EXPOSE 5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

I am building the dontainer like this:

```
docker build -t api-test:v0 .
```

And run it with this command:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 api-test:v0
```

The output of the run command is:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
```

I have also tried different approaches of binding the URL:

- as `http://+:5000`, `http://0.0.0.0:5000`, `http://localhost:5000`, ...
- via CLI parameters `--urls` / `--server.urls`

but without success. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Whats your operating system? Is it windows/osx or linux?

Comment: I forgot to mention. It's running on Windows... I updated it in the question

Comment: run `docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <container_ID>` for its IP. Replace `localhost` with the IP. See if that works.

Comment: @pizycki Unfortunately thats not working either... Timeout takes considerably longer though

Comment: Are you running on Windows 10 or earlier? They use different virt mechanisms.

Comment: Running on Windows 10

Comment: Few debug questions:
1) Docker for Windows requires Windows 10 pro. Are you using Docker for Windows? https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/ Docker for Windows uses the IP address that @pizycki suggested.
2) The other option is you're using Docker Toolbox, which requires using docker-machine to set-up. Then you use the machine ip `docker-machine ip mymachinename`
3) Neither Docker for Windows or Docker Toolbox can bind to localhost. This is a Windows limitation.
4) What's the output of `docker version` ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure your service is listening on all ports using `http://*:500` or similar (if it prints `localhost` when running, it won't work).
2. If you set up your docker environment with VirtualBox and used e.g. docker-machine, you n need to use the IP address of the virtual machine that runs the docker containers. you can get the IP via `docker-machine ip default`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
```

Binding to localhost will not work for your scenario. You need to get the app to bind to 0.0.0.0 for the docker port forwarding to work. Once you do that, you should be able to reach the app on the VM IP, port 5000

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried it out but still no luck

Comment: @DanielLerps, does your VM VirtualBox has an IP lan-network reachable? I think that is the point

Answer (score 1):

I found a way round this. All you need to do is edit launchSettings.json change to  `"applicationUrl": "http://*:5000/"` of your app setting. Build the image. Then run the image `docker run -d -p 81:5000 aspnetcoreapp` after it runs get ip address of the container `docker exec container_id ipconfig`. Then in browser http://container_ip:5000/api/values. For some reason it does not work http://localhost:81 still need to figure out why that is.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently with Docker version 20.x. The comment above provided good lights. If anyone faces the same issue here is how I've solved: Edit launchSettings.json to

```
"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001;http://host.docker.internal:5001",
```

This will let you test your web API locally and also to be consumed from the container.